# mysqli prepare statement Does it deal with things like apostraphe

Tags: php, mysqli

within my web app there is no doubt the posibility for user's to enter an apostraphe. This will btreak the sql statment if it's not escaped. Will mysqli prepared statements escape this for me?

Comment: Upvoting this because while this is a very basic question, it seems not clearly answered in the mysqli manual, and with things like this it's better to ask one time too often than one time too few.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will mysqli prepared statements escape this for me?

Yup, that's what they're for.

Comment: Thanks alot Pekka rep points for you!! I know t'sbasic but I'd rather look like an idiot now then few months down the line